# Search through all sheets for a string which have a specific value in the cell next to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a custom formula script that loops through all sheets containing "@" in their tab name.  In there, I then look through a range to find the string that I am searching for (given as an argument).  If I find that string in the range, I run some other code to check other cells.

The important part here is finding the string in the range.  Here is my code for doing that.

```
    /**
    * Searches through the box scores and counts Goaltender Wins.
    *
    * @param {"Hollywood|Hattricks|HOL"} teamName The team to search for.
    * @param {"Z1"} dummy The cell to store random number in order to refresh values on editing the box scores.
    * @return {number} The number of times the item appears in the range(s).
    * @customfunction
    */
    function calcGoaltenderWins(username, dummy) {

      var count = 0;

      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function (s) {
        //regular season sheets
        if (s.getName().indexOf("@") >= 0 && s.getName().indexOf(":") === -1) {
          //if sheet is finalized
          if (s.getRange("U37").getDisplayValue() != "Live ⬤") {
            //if the home team won
            if (s.getRange("Q11").getValue() < s.getRange("Q12").getValue()) {
              //check if goaltender is on the player list for that game
              s.getRange("Y5:Y12")
              .getValues()
              .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a.concat(b);
              })
              .forEach(function (v) {
                if (v === username) count += 1;
              });
            }
            //if the away team won
            if (s.getRange("Q12").getValue() < s.getRange("Q11").getValue()) {
              //check if goaltender is on the player list for that game
              s.getRange("D5:D12")
              .getValues()
              .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a.concat(b);
              })
              .forEach(function (v) {
                if (v === username) count += 1;
              });
            }
          }
        }
      });
      return count;
    }
```

[image: Here is what the sheet looks like for reference.]

The thing I want to figure out is how to check if the string I am checking for has a specific value 2 cells to the left of it. This value should be "G".

For example, I used the formula `=calcGoaltenderWins("Name", dummy)`. If the name "Name" is found inside the range D5:D12 (specifically in D5), then it should also only check if B5 (the cell 2 to the left) if it equals "G" in order to continue running the code.  If it does not equal "G", then it should not respond to the string it found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function calcGoaltenderWins(username, dummy) {
  var count = 0;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=ss.getSheets()
  shts.forEach(function(s) {
    if (s.getName().indexOf("@")>=0 && s.getName().indexOf(":")==-1) {
      if (s.getRange("U37").getDisplayValue()!="Live ⬤") {
        if (s.getRange("Q11").getValue() < s.getRange("Q12").getValue()) {
          s.getRange("Y5:Y12").getValues().reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b);}).forEach(function(v){if (v==username)count+=1;});
        }
        if(s.getRange("Q12").getValue() < s.getRange("Q11").getValue()) {
          let v=s.getRange("B5:B12").getValues();//added
          s.getRange("D5:D12").getValues().reduce(function(a,b,i) {if(v[i][0]=="G"){return a.concat(b)}else{return a;};}).forEach(function(v){if (v==username)count += 1;//edited
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I will try this.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: This worked exactly as I described.  Thank you very much!